# HDMI->VGA adapter prevents me getting sound from my laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, external-display

My laptop only has HDMI out and the external monitors I have access to here (including a projector) are old VGA-only.

I have a HDMI->VGA adapter but when I use this I lose any sound output from the laptop, presumably because it thinks a HMI cable is connected and is sending the sound that way?

I can't get sound through the laptop speakers or the headphone-out 3.5mm socket. Is this likely something I can resolve in Windows 10 settings?

Comment: Your converting a digital signal that has sound and video to an analog signal that only has video.

Comment: @Ramhound well yes of course I know I can't send audio down VGA but the question is how to make my laptop stop trying ;)

Comment: Change the audio device within windows and the application itself.

Comment: This works for me on Windows 10: "audio settings" / "set output device"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the audio ouput channel follow the next steps:

1. Press the Windows key
2. Type 'Settings' and open the Settings
3. In the Settings view type 'Manage audio'
4. Open 'Manage audio devices'
5. Select the right output channel
6. Click at the bottom on 'Set Default'
7. Click 'OK'
8. Depending on the program, you may need to configure the audio output channel in the program also.

Shorter path (thanks to PWtr):

1. Right click on sound level icon in taskbar
2. Playback devices
3. Continue at step 5 (see above)

You may need to restart the program before it takes effect. Also do not forget to check the output level. The output level is stored separatly per device.

Comment: There is shorter path: Right click on sound level icon in taskbar -> playback devices

Comment: @PTwr correct, but not every computer is the same and a user may not have the icon directly visible. I choose for an anwer that users will always be able to figure out. But I will add it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: For command line freaks: `control mmsys.cpl sounds` :)